# Angular action on a class change

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I use a jQuery slider and need to detect on `slideBl` element when it gets a `cycle-slide-active` class, which is moving from slide to slide continuously.

here is my Jade(html):

```
#slideshow2(slideshow, data-cycle-speed="500", data-cycle-prev="#prev", data-cycle-next="#next")
div.slideBl(ng-repeat="image in images" ng-init="rating = image.rate" class="slide{{image.id}}")
    span(star-rating, rating-value="rating" max="5" on-rating-selected="rateFunction(rating)")
    img.slide.img-responsive(ng-src="{{image.url}}")
    div() {{image.count}}
```

I have read about Angular's $observe and $watch, and thanks to Ben Nadel's tutorial, I end up with next directive:

```
.directive('slideBl', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "C",
        link:
            // I bind the UI events to the local scope.
            function ( $scope, element, attrs ) {

            setTimeout(function () {
                // Register an $observe callback.
                attrs.$observe(
                    "slideBl",
                    function innerObserveFunction() {
                        console.log( "Inner $observe() fired." );
                    }
                );

                // Register a $watch callback.
                $scope.$watch(
                    function innerWatchFunction() {
                        console.log( "Inner $watch() fired." );
                    });
                }, 250);
        }
    };
});
```

With this code I can detect all `slideBl` elements after page loads, but how do I keep on tracking for `cycle-slide-active` class changes, so I could count how many times slide was shown?

Comment: you are watching for the directive attribute not for a dat attribute in the observe, what i mean, i would use an attribute to instantiate the directive and another which is proper of the directive to observe its changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to watch the class attribute and check if the `cycle-slide-active` class was added ([**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/RZ1gskm8zL12nKcQmqR1?p=preview)):

```js
app.directive('slideBl', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "C",
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs ) {
            $scope.$watch(function() {
                return element.attr('class');
            }, function(newClasses, oldClasses) {
               if (containsSlideClass(newClasses) && (!containsSlideClass(oldClasses) || newClasses == oldClasses)) {
                   console.log('Slide active');
               }
            });

            function containsSlideClass(classStr) {
                return classStr.split(' ').indexOf('cycle-slide-active') !== -1;
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
I think my angular-level is "not there yet" ))
Now I learned a lot, thanks again.